# Self Left Join with no identitical row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a self left join on a table which looks like below-

| SystemID | UserID | DateTimeStamp | Entry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:04:48 | New Process :30/07/23 |
| 1232 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:04:47 | Task : PQR |
| 1214 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:04:42 | Task : PQR |
| 1211 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:04:26 | Task : PQR |
| 1209 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:03:56 | New Process :30/07/23 |
| 1206 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:03:56 | Task : LMN |
| 1201 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:03:47 | Task : LMN |
| 1189 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:03:26 | Task : LMN |
| 1167 | DEF | 29/07/2023 21:58:30 | New Process :30/07/23 |
| 1166 | DEF | 29/07/2023 21:58:29 | Task : ZZZ |
| 1160 | DEF | 29/07/2023 21:58:23 | Task : ZZZ |
| 1154 | DEF | 29/07/2023 21:58:22 | Task : ZZZ |

The table says that SystemID 1234 is a New Process and is for the Task PQR. Similarly, SystemID 1209 is a New Process for Task LMN and SystemID 1167 is a New Process for Task ZZZ

Is there a way I can get the 'New Process' row with the top most 'Task'row  and the related UserID and DateTimeStamp linked to it like below -

| SystemID | UserID | DateTimeStamp | Entry | Task | TaskDateTime | TaskUserID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:04:48 | New Process:30/07/23 | PQR | 29/07/2023 22:04:48 | ABC |
| 1209 | ABC | 29/07/2023 22:03:56 | New Process:30/07/23 | LMN | 29/07/2023 22:03:56 | ABC |
| 1167 | DEF | 29/07/2023 21:58:30 | New Process:30/07/23 | ZZZ | 29/07/2023 21:58:39 | DEF |

Is there any way I can achieve the above result set?

Comment: in your expected result how does `ID 1167` gets task `PQR`?

Comment: Sorry about both the mistakes. I have made the changes

Comment: What have you tried?   What exactly do you mean by 'top-most' row?   What do you mean by 'The table says that SystemID 1234 is a New Process and is for the Task PQR', I see nothing to indicate that link.

Comment: yes exactly there is no link between the two rows (row having Entry = 'New Process%' and row having Entry = 'Task %'). But I want The row where Entry = 'New Process% ' linked to the next row to it with Entry = 'Task %'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `APPLY()` operator

```
select *
from   table1 t
       outer apply
       (
           select top 1 *
           from   table1 x
           where  x.UserID = t.UserID
           and    x.DateTimeStamp < t.DateTimeStamp
           order by x.DateTimeStamp desc
       ) a
where  t.Entry like 'New Process%'
```

Or `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
  select *, rn = row_number() over(partition by UserID order by DateTimeStamp desc)
  from   table1
)
select *
from   cte c1
       left join cte c2 on  c2.UserID = c1.UserID
                        and c2.rn     = c1.rn + 1
where  c1.Entry like 'New Process%'
```

Or `lead()` or `lag()` window function

```
with cte as
(
  select *, 
         prevEntry = lead(Entry) over(partition by UserID order by DateTimeStamp desc),
         prevDT    = lead(DateTimeStamp) over(partition by UserID order by DateTimeStamp desc)
  from   table1
)
select *
from   cte c
where  c.Entry like 'New Process%'
```